# Embed 2 Dynamic UITableViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have two UITableView's embedded into a UIViewController. Both are dynamic and retrieve the different data. The issue is that the **`indexPath`** is used in both tables when using `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

Is there a work-around here? I am referencing my entities like so:

```
//tableView2 has a cell named differently
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";

//reference the cells to the right tables
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
UITableViewCell *cell2 = [self.tableView2 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];

//create access to details the cell will display from the core date
entity1 * e1 = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//this is the issue
//entity2 * e2 = [self.fetchedResultsController2 objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

The issue as mentioned is the indexPath. If I try to run the app with both entities equating to their respective fetchedResults it causes an error due to the indexPath being reused. If I create another indexPath it causes this error (understandably so):

> 'Invalid index path for use with UITableView.  Index paths passed to table view must contain exactly two indices specifying the section and row.  Please use the category on NSIndexPath in UITableView.h if possible.'

My question is, how do I reuse or create a separate reference to the NSIndexPath inside the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method, or is there a workaround?

I have already attempted using if/if else statements inside the method but this displays the same number of cells in both tables; if table1 has 10 rows there will be 10 rows in table2 regardless of content.

The below code is possibly incorrect, I am not experienced enough implementing two table views to know, but it's not the main issue:

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    if ([self fetchedResultsController]){

        return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];

    }

    if ([self fetchedResultsController2]) {
        return [[self.fetchedResultsController2 sections] count];
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{


    if ([self fetchedResultsController]){
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];

    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    }

    if ([self fetchedResultsController2]){
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController2 sections]objectAtIndex:section];

        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need an if-else block in cellForRowAtIndexPath just like you have in numberOfRowsInSection and numberOfSectionsInTableView.

Comment: I knew there was something I forgot to add in the question. Will update. That does not seem to work either sadly.

Comment: You should post the actual code you tried with the if-else block in cellForRowAtIndexPath. It should work if you do it properly.

Comment: If you are sharing the delegate object between two tableviews, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method should return the appropriate result based on the `tableView` parameter.  You don't show the code doing this... you show code doing something for both tableViews regardless of which tableView invokes the method.  As you say, the indexPath only pertains to one.

Comment: share your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code then we can identify your error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you don't have to create two sections.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
```

Then you have to set your Rows according to your tableView

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{


    if (tableView == self.tableView1){
        //Return the count you want inside self.tableView1
    }

    else if (tableView == self.tableView2){
        //Return the count you want inside self.tableView2
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Finally inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set your table Values according to your TableView.

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
           if (tableView == self.tableView1){
              static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
              //reference the cells to the right tables
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
         }

    else if (tableView == self.tableView2){
               static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";
               UITableViewCell *cell2 = [self.tableView2 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];
         }
    else{
        return 0;
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set tags for tableviews. and in cellforRowAt IndexPath

```
if(tabaleView.tag==100)
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; 
}
else
{
  UITableViewCell *cell2 = [self.tableView2 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```